# How to make a loop for multiple scatterplots in python?

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to automate the plotting procedure of a large dataframe matrix. The goal is to plot each column with an other column. Each column represents a variable. See also the image below.

F.e: sex vs age, sex vs BMI, sex vs smoke, sex vs type and so on.

For the sake of clearity, I have simplified the problem to image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY4Rt.png)

Initially, I tried to plot each combination by hand. But this is rather a time-consuming excersize and not what I want.

I tried also this (not working):

```
variables = ["Sex", "Age", "BMI"]
for variable in variables:
plt.scatter(df.variable, df.variable)
plt.xlabel('variable')
plt.ylabel('variable')
plt.title('variable vs. variable')
plt.show()
```

Any help is welcome!

PS: If it would be a simple excersize to incorporate a linear regression on the combination of variables as well, that would also be appreciated.

Greetings,

Nadia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you coded plots each column against itself.  What you described is a nested loop.  A simple upgrade is

```
col_choice = ["Sex", "Age", "BMI"]

for pos, axis1 in enumerate(col_choice):   # Pick a first col
    for axis2 in enumerate(col_choice[pos+1:]):   # Pick a later col
        plt.scatter(df.loc[:, axis1], df.loc[:, axis2])
```

I *think* this generates a series acceptable to `scatter`.

Does that help?  If you want to be more "Pythonic", then look into `itertools.product` to generate your column choices.

Comment: Whoops!  Sorry; you need to access the column named by the variable *value* `axis1` ... you know how to do that?

Comment: That's because you specified a particular (constant) column, rather than taking the value from the `axis` variables, as my solutions specifies.

Comment: Thanks, Prune. It worked. For the reader, one has to adjust for axis2, choosing the second column.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dummy dataframe, or load your own with pd.read_csv()

columns = ["sex", "age", "BMI", "smoke", "type"]
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,0,0,1,0], [23,16,94,18,24], [32, 26, 28, 23, 19], [0,1,1,1,0], [1,2,2,2,1]]).T, columns=columns)


x_col = "sex"
y_columns = ["age", "BMI", "smoke"]


for y_col in y_columns:

    figure = plt.figure
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.scatter(data[x_col], data[y_col])
    ax.set_xlabel(x_col)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_col)
    ax.set_title("{} vs {}".format(x_col, y_col))

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Basically, if you have your dataset saved as a `.csv` file, you can load it with pandas using `pd.read_csv()`, and use the column names as keys to access the corresponding rows, and iterate on that (here I created a dummy dataframe just for the sake of it).

Regarding the linear regression part, you should check out the [scikit-learn library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning). It has a lot of regression models for many different tasks like regression, classification and clustering

Comment: Thanks for your help neko. As for now, pycharm is not providing the plots for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combinations` from `itertools`. This way you will get an iterator with tuples of the combinations.

```py
from itertools import combinations


print(list(combinations(df.columns, 2)))
```

The code you need would look like this:

```py
from itertools import combinations


for col1, col2 in combinations(df.columns, 2): # <-----
    plt.scatter(df[col1], df[col2])
    plt.show()
```