# How to plot each column with each column from Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I were searching how create scatterplot between each column with each column. Similar question to this one and I followed the code from answer:

[How to make a loop for multiple scatterplots in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974174/how-to-make-a-loop-for-multiple-scatterplots-in-python)

What I done is:

```
columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

for pos, axis1 in enumerate(columns):   
    for axis2 in enumerate(columns[pos+1:]): 
        plt.scatter(df.loc[:, axis1], df.loc[:, axis2].iloc[:,1])
```

But in this solution I'm getting everything on one single plot, I want to make it separately, how I can achieve that?

Comment: Consider [Seaborn's pairplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html).

Comment: I want to have every graph separately, not all at the one so sns.pairplot for me is not solution but thank you

Comment: put `plt.show()` after `plt.scatter` (inside the two loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yehla has a good solution, but if you want to graph each plot on the same figure, create a new `plt.subplot()` each loop.

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

col_count = 2
columns = list(df.columns)
row_count = math.ceil((len(columns)*len(columns))/col_count)

plt_dict = {}
count = 1
for k,v in enumerate(columns):
    for column2 in columns[k:]:     
        ax = plt.subplot(row_count,col_count,count)
        ax.set_title(f'{v} x {column2}')
        ax.scatter(df[v],df[column2])
        
        count += 1
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I understood it you want to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 1], [7.0, 3.2, 2],
                   [6.4, 3.2, 3], [5.9, 3.0, 4]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
for i, col1 in enumerate(['col1', 'col2','col3']):
    for col2 in cols[i:]:
        df.plot.scatter(x=col1, y=col2, c='DarkBlue')
```